# Basic Class Inheritance

Tags: ruby, class

I have two files:

answer.rb

```
class Answer
  def decision(string)
    if string == 'Richard'
      puts "Hello"
    else
      puts "I dont know you"
    end
  end
end
```

question.rb

```
require './answer'

class Question < Answer
  puts "What is your name?"
  response = gets.chomp
  puts decision("#{response}")
end
```

How do I access the method in class `Answer` from class `Question` given the file is not enough? If I remove the the class `Answer`, then everything works.

Answer (score 4):

To make your example work you need to call your code. For instance you can amend your `Question` class with the following code :

```
#question.rb

require './answer'

class Question < Answer

  def ask
    puts "What is your name?"
    response = gets.chomp

    puts decision(response)
  end
end

Question.new.ask
```

The inheritance will be that your instance of question (i.e. `Question.new`) will be inherited from `Answer` => it will have both methods (in your case 'ask' and 'decision').

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
puts self.new.decision(response) # no need for string interpolation.
```

`#decision` is an instance method of `Answer` class, so it will be available as an instance method of the class `Question`. Now inside the class, self is set to the **class** itself, thus the bare method call like your, will throw error as **no method found**. Thus you have to create an instance of the class `Answer` or `Question`, and on that instance you have to call the method.

Complete code :

```
class Answer
  def decision(string)
    if string == 'Richard'
      puts "Hello"
    else
      puts "I dont know you"
    end
  end
end

class Question < Answer
  puts "What is your name?"
  response = gets.chomp
  puts self.new.decision(response)
end
```

Run the code:

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby so.rb
What is your name?
arup
I dont know you

(arup~>Ruby)$
```

Comment: ok thanks, but could you explain what is happening there?

Comment: @Richlewis You should add an instance method (e.g. `def ask`) to your `Question` class. In that instance method you *can* call `decision`. And then do `Question.new.ask`.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is answering his question, but I wouldn't recommend a design requiring creating an a new instance of `self`.

Comment: @MarkThomas I agree with you. *Mischa* provided good way to handle it.

Comment: @MarkThomas Problem is hurryness, I always start, first to tell, why is not working, logic, then a fix, then if I have a good idea for that. But people start from the last part sometimes, so I started to feel be lazy! :)